# How to get the current server request timeout in Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, akka-http

Akka HTTP allows request timeouts to be set from either the global setting in `application.conf` or modified on a per-route basis with directives.

How can we get the request timeout for the current request and route? Something like

```
withRequestTimeout(FiniteDuration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
  extractRequestTimeout { timeout =>
   complete(s"request would have timed out in $timeout") // request would have timed out in 5 seconds
  }
}
```

would be perfect.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: Shouldn't matter to the question, but I'm implementing a high level request timeout handler similar to what's discussed here https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/607. I'd like to get the current request timeout so I can set the high level timeout to that value, and then update the request timeout to something a bit larger than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible in Akka HTTP using the `extractRequestTimeout` directive. [PR](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/pull/1828) and [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/timeout-directives/extractRequestTimeout.html).

```
val timeout1 = 500.millis
val timeout2 = 1000.millis
val route =
  path("timeout") {
    withRequestTimeout(timeout1) {
      extractRequestTimeout { t1 ⇒
        withRequestTimeout(timeout2) {
          extractRequestTimeout { t2 ⇒
            complete(
              if (t1 == timeout1 && t2 == timeout2) StatusCodes.OK
              else StatusCodes.InternalServerError
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```